# Como executo um algoritmo quando o usuario deixa de tocar na tela?

Tags: java, android

Gostaria de, quando o usuário pressionar a tela, abrir um menu horizontal com 4 opções onde a opção a qual ele soltar o dedo em cima será a selecionada.

O evento de pressionar eu ja sei.
seria este:

```
btn_operacao.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            //algoritmo . . .
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Qual seria o evento para pegar o momento em que o usuário remove seu dedo da tela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O OnLongClickListener não serve para isso. Ele é para todos os passos que formam um evento de clique longo (aquele que costuma ser usado para trazer o menu de contexto).

Você precisa ir para um nível mais baixo-- usar o [OnTouchListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html), em conjunto com as ações [ACTION_DOWN](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_DOWN) e [ACTION_UP](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_UP)

```
minhaView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener () {
  public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
      // mostre o menu que aparece quando o usuário toca na tela
    } else if (event.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
      // o usuário soltou o toque. Execute a lógica de decidir qual opção foi selecionada
    }
    return true;
  }
});
```

Também pode ser interessante tratar o caso do [ACTION_CANCEL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#ACTION_CANCEL), que é quando o usuário (de alguma forma) cancelou o toque sem soltar o dedo na sua View. Nesse caso, trate como se nenhuma opção tivesse sido escolhida.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou! Fecha ali no fim do códico com um ); Abraço!

Comment: Verdade. Consertado. :)